# Mathematical Induction on a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, induction

I could not solve this problem:

Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty = 1^2 + 2^2 + \ldots + n^2 = \frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1) $

Prove this works for all $n \in J$ where $J$ is the set of all positive integers.

My thought process:

Let

$$p(1) : 1 = \frac{1}{6}(1)(1+1)(2(1)+1) = \frac{6}{6} = 1$$

Let let p(n) be defined as

$$ p(n):  1^2 + 2^2 + \ldots + n^2 = \frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1), \text{and} $$

let $p(n)$ hold true for all $n \in J$.

Then,

$$p(n+1) : L.H.S = p(n) + (n+1)^2 = \frac{1}{6}(n+1)((n+1)+1)(2(n+1) + 1) = R.H.S. $$

But upon expanding the R.H.S. and expanding the L.H.S. I could not find a way to get

$$ p(n) + (n+1)^2 = \frac{1}{6}(n+1)((n+1)+1)(2(n+1) + 1) $$

Both end up having $2n^2$, was I supposed to then say that the

$$ \text{L.H.S} \approx  2n^2 = 2n^2 \approx \text{R.H.S} $$

and prove it using the approximations? If the question was formed as

Let,

$$\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty = 1^2 + 2^2 + \ldots + n^2 \leq \frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1) $$

Then I feel as if this would be correct, but to say that they are equal to me would have to show the L.H.S = R.H.S, not L.H.S. $\approx$ R.H.S.

Ask questions if I am not being as clear as I possible, and thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Not sure on your $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$. Surely you don't mean $\infty$?

Comment: Not really related, but very cool, I had to post it: https://ds055uzetaobb.cloudfront.net/image_optimizer/d7364bd51b9054239abc5337e7c443cbccbff4ee.png

Comment: The line 'let $p(n)$ hold true for all $n \in J$' doesn't really work. You don't want that - that's what you're trying to prove. You just want to assume $p(k)$ for some $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p(n)=\tfrac16n(n+1)(2n+1)$, then 
$$p(n) + (n+1)^2 = \tfrac16n(n+1)(2n+1)+(n+1)^2$$
$$=(n+1)\cdot\big(\tfrac16n(2n+1) + (n+1)\big)$$
$$=\tfrac16(n+1)\cdot(n(2n+1)+6(n+1))$$
$$=\tfrac16(n+1)\cdot((2n^2+n)+(6n+6))$$
$$=\tfrac16(n+1)\cdot(2n^2+7n+6)$$
$$=\tfrac16(n+1)\cdot(n+2)(2n+3)$$
$$=\tfrac16(n+1)(\underbrace{(n+1)+1}_{n+2})(\underbrace{2(n+1)+1}_{2n+3})$$
$$=p(n+1)$$

Comment: The bamboozle. Did not even think about having an $(n+1)^2$ on the right hand side, let alone factoring out the n+1. Learn something new every day. It is crazy how something I struggled with, someone has done in 7 steps, and made it look so easy. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Would like to show you how I would do it as I'm not so sure that your layout is quite correct:

---

Let $P(n)$ be the proposition statement $$P(n): 1^2 + 2^2 + \ldots + n^2 = \frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)$$

Then

$$1^2=\frac{1}{6}(1)(1+1)(2(1)+1)=1\implies P(1)$$

If $P(k)$ is true for some $k$, then:
$$P(k): 1^2 + 2^2 + \ldots + k^2 = \frac{1}{6}k(k+1)(2k+1)$$

Then $$1^2 + 2^2 + \ldots + k^2+(k+1)^2 = \frac{1}{6}k(k+1)(2k+1)+(k+1)^2$$

$$= \frac{1}{6}(k(k+1)(2k+1)+6(k+1)^2)$$

$$= \frac{1}{6}(2k^3+3k^2+k+6k^2+12k+6)$$

$$= \frac{1}{6}(2k^3+9k^2+13k+6)$$

Now, as this is a proof by induction, you know what you are trying to get, so you can multiply out $\frac{1}{6}(k+1)((k+1)+1)(2(k+1)+1)$ rather than factorising the expression.

$$\frac{1}{6}(k+1)((k+1)+1)(2(k+1)+1)=\frac{1}{6}(k+1)(k+2)(2k+3)$$

$$=\frac{1}{6}(k+1)(2k^2+7k+6)$$

$$=\frac{1}{6}(2k^3+7k^2+6k+2k^2+7k+6)$$

$$=\frac{1}{6}(2k^3+9k^2+13k+6)$$

Therefore,

$$1^2 + 2^2 + \ldots +(k+1)^2 = \frac{1}{6}(k+1)((k+1)+1)(2(k+1)+1)$$

$$\implies P(k+1)$$

---

$P(1) \land (P(k)\implies P(k+1)) \implies (\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}^+)\,\,\, P(n) \,\,\, \square$

Comment: thank you for you answer! Did not think about adding the $(n+1)^2$ on the R.H.S.